# Eclipse IDE doesn't open up after creating a project

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, ide

When I run eclipse for the first time, it runs perfectly till I create a project in it.

But when I create a project, it is not opening up. It's showing in the task manager.

Every time I delete all the. metadata file from the workspace, then it will open perfectly again.

I don't understand why?

Please Help Me

Thank You.

```
!SESSION 2021-01-14 22:41:04.775 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.18.0.I20201202-1800
java.version=13.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-01-14 22:41:14.846
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-01-14 22:41:14.846
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@507187c1,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@2220c5f7,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-01-14 22:41:22.016
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.helpers.EmptyWorkspaceHelper.dispose(EmptyWorkspaceHelper.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.helpers.EmptyWorkspaceHelper$Listener.widgetDisposed(EmptyWorkspaceHelper.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1315)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3675)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2021-01-14 22:41:22.049
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.dispose(WorkbenchPart.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ExtendedMarkersView.dispose(ExtendedMarkersView.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:421)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:945)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:220)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2021-01-14 23:14:08.969
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4875)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4790)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4761)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.removePage(PageBookView.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.dispose(PageBookView.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:421)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:945)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:220)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend ever deleting the ".metadata" directory. Try creating an entirely new workspace by adding "-data pathtoworkspace" on the shortcut command line.

Comment: Thank you David M. Karr
I ll try that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the resolution.

I just uninstall the previous version of Java(13.0.1) then install Java version 13.0.2.

and set the environmental system path again. That's it.

Now Eclipse IDE runs perfectly.

Thank You.